# Make Child Nested Div to float right of parent

Tags: html, css, css-float

Div formations:

[image: Div formations]

I'd like to make an inner div float right of the parent, regardless of the width of the parent and child div's.
I need to move the Refresh button to the right of Parent where I added the red color box(please see Div formations link).

Comment: does `float: right` works? If not, can you paste your current code here.

Comment: @Bk Santigo .. Inner div's width is auto.

Comment: You are using a border around of dashboard and refresh button what was that is it div ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to go here is to use the margin-left attribute on the inner div in order to give the illusion of floating to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here is what you can do. **EDIT: Go to bottom for new edit!**

Your parent div (id="parent")
Child div (id="child")

You need CSS and HTML to do this.

1. Make your parent and child divs nested properly.

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <!-- Whatever goes in your div -->
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <!-- Whatever goes in your div -->
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Now you need to create a css class for your parent and child div's.

```css
/* this will use the ID of the div, to use a class its .parent and you need to set the class parameter of the div. */
#parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #333 /* Grey */
}
#child {
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #2e00ff /* Blue */;
}
#child2 {
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ff0000 /* Red */;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <!-- Whatever goes in your div -->
  </div>
  <div id="child2">
    <!-- Whatever goes in your div -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully, this helps! -InvincibleM

**Edit: You should be able to place any fillers like a button in the div element.**

Answer (score 0):

this may works perfect for you

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="other-items">
        may be large chunks ..
    </div>

    <div class="right">  <!-- separate the element and give position -->
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.other-items {
    width: 98%;
    /*padding-right: 15px;*/
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css approach to get it
use one `parent` div then inside a button `parent` div,use `float:right` to button parent div and use `display:inline-block` to align in single line.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.dashboard {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.refresh {
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.setting {
  border: 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="dashboard">Dashboard</div>
  <div class="buttonGroup">
    <div class="refresh">refresh</div>
    <div class="setting">Setting</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.parent {
    overflow:hidden;
    background: orange;
}  
.child1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

.child2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">Child1</div>
    <div class="child2">Child2</div>
</div>
```